# Two label rules - display dependency

Tags: qgis, labeling, overlapping-features

I want to make a labels for point layer which has two columns: town name and number of residents.  I made two rules: first for names and second for numbers. Each of them has different styles  so I had to split them for two rules.

If these Towns are in short distance to others, my label rules are hiding label of town names, BUT dont hide number of residents. (look at pic. below). I'd like to combine both label rules that if town name can't be displayed then number of residents is also hidden.

Qgis 3.16.10

Red colour on pic. means those labels were hidden.
[image: x]

Answer (score 1):

Labels can be render as 'html': so use 'table', 'font size' or 'font face' and/or 'font color'.
[image]

And for having all of your labels, forced them to appear!
[image]

Comment: depends of number of residends, town name label size increases, can I do that in html?. second thing is that i cant use that checkbox from second screen because hiding will stop working totally ;p

Comment: HTML part is just what it is written… set the size as you would do normally!